# Triggering .draggable() event on mousedown?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a way to change the event that triggers the .draggable() element?
I would like to start dragging the element on mousedown event instead the of default.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, In order to drag an element the user have to double click the element and then the .draggable() will be triggered, I would like to make it simpler and start dragging on mouse down event. I hope that my goal is clearer now, please let me know if this isn't the case. this is my code example: jsbin.com/ujOQIZE/5

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#init-canvas').dblclick(function() { 
  $(this).draggable();
});
```

This is what you need. Only after the #init-canvas is doubleclicked first the object is draggable.

Comment: I've tried this code: $('#init-canvas').on('mousedown', function (e) { console.log('dragging');
                            return $(this).draggable();
                        }); but the dragging doesn't start on mouse down, because it doesn't change the event that is triggering the .draggable(). obviously, the console.log is activated on mouse down...